# How to wait until the completion of asynchronous steps?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, submit

I have a form where I need to run a number of validation actions before submitting. These actions involve asynchronous steps like ajax calls.

How can I tell the form to wait until all validation actions have been completed before submitting?

My validation function looks like this (pseudo-code):

```
function preSubmit() {
    // validate field 1
    ajax({
        ...
        onSuccess:...
    });
    // validate field 2
    ajax({
        ...
        onSuccess:...
    });
    // fields 3, 4, etc.
}
```

My current issue is that the form gets submitted before the onSuccess callbacks are completed.

I could of course make my ajax calls synchronous, but I am trying to avoid it because of the performance impact.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, look into `$.when`

Comment: Why not just submit the form and have the server tell you if it's valid or not?

Comment: @Kolink to save one trip to the server. In my case some validations use external services (for example address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, then you might want to consider `JQuery.Deferred or Promise`

You call each ajax request (or function that contains the request), when the previous call is complete (successfully or failed).

If you use $.when you can manage failed request by the `.then` callback. If you use promises then you can make use the `.done` `.fail` and `.always` callbacks in various scenarios.

```
$.when($.ajax("...."), $.ajax("...."))
  .then(...);
```

Resources:

- http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/
- http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: I forgot a key constraint in my question (the submit action is external to the preSubmit function) and before I knew it all the replies were headed in a different direction. I am marking this one as answer as it seems to be the most appropriate considering the information I provided.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should only have to fire off one ajax event. If you must include multiple ajax events, you may fire the async requests in sequence(synchronously) using the success callback function. Here is an example.

```
    function preSubmit() {
        $.ajax({
            error: handleError,
            success: stepTwo
        });
    }
    function stepTwo() {
        $.ajax({
            error: handleError,
            success: stepThree
        });
    }
```

Comment: This makes sense, but as I said in the question this is not very efficient as calls need to wait for each other.

Comment: Having multiple ajax calls is in and of itself "not very efficient". With respect to efficiency in terms of time and assuming all the fields you want to validate are true, then yes, it would probably be faster (by a few milliseconds). However, consider the situation when one or more of the fields are invalid. You will have fired off  every possible ajax event even if the first one returned invalid. I and others would probably consider the wasted server resources / bandwidth much more of a slap in the face to efficiency than just making the user wait a few more milliseconds.

Comment: Thx for the commnent. It's not how I have things set up right now, but I'll need to reconsider it. Also, I want to inform the user about all the validation issues, not just return an invalid status.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to fire only one ajax call (apparently with multiple field's data).

Answer (score 0):

Create an "errorMsg" variable and set it to "waiting" initially, then have your aynchc code update it.

In your form submission code, check for the value of the field. It's it's not "ready", don't submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's set timeout function. The code will be like this,

```
function preSubmit() {
 //set a variable which increments after each Ajax call success.
var successCount=0;
// validate field 1
ajax({
    ...
    onSuccess: function(){
       successCount++; 
    }
});
// validate field 2
ajax({
    ...
     onSuccess: function(){
       successCount++; 
    }
});

  var wait = function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        // check whether "successCount" is equal to number of validations done
         //here it is 2
        if(successCount==2){
        //call function say,"submitForm" which submit the form
          submitForm();
        }else{
          //All validations are not completed, wait until it completes
          wait();
         }
        },1000);
     }
     wait();
}
```

This way you can use asynchronous Ajax calls effectively.